# Is there any benefits of identifying input_shape in the first layer of a Keras model?

Tags: keras, tf.keras

I suppose that the `input_shape` argument is optional for the first layer of a `Sequential` Keras model as in the following simple code snippet:

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)), 
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')
])
```

If we don't identify it, it will be inferred from the first batch of data. The only difference that I can imagine is that when we define `input_shape`, the model can be initialized sooner. Are there any real benefits of identifying this argument?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, the only difference is when exactly the model is going to be built. This difference can matter, for example, printing the model summary or saving the model before providing any data will only work if the `input_shape` is specified.